# Mostrar los productos que no se han vendido en el 2018

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar los que no existen use esto:
R=  producto.nombre
Desde: producto, pedido
Donde: producto.cod_prod - pedido.cod_prod

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que este query resuelve lo que necesitás:

```
SELECT PR.nombre
FROM Producto AS PR
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM PEDIDO AS PE
    WHERE PE.cod_prod = PR.cod_prod
      AND YEAR(PE.fecha_ped) = 2018)
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!